# T-distribution with confidence level in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jstat

What's the [jStat](http://jstat.github.io/) function to calculate the t-distribution with a predefined confidence level?

```
jStat.???(1, 0.99) # == 63.67
jStat.???(10, 0.99) # == 3.17
jStat.???(1, 0.95) # == 12.69
```

http://uregina.ca/~gingrich/tt.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jStat.studentt.inv( p, dof )](https://jstat.github.io/distributions.html#jStat.studentt) like so:

```
function tdist(df, conf_lvl) {
  return jStat.studentt.inv((1 - (1 - conf_lvl) / 2), df)
}
```

`.inv(p, dof)` returns a desired value for a given *p* = (1 - *alpha*) where *alpha* value is the amount of area in one trail, wheras the confidence level is (1 - 2 * *alpha*) [it excludes area in both trails]